# Why do I have .htaccess files in multiple directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking through my server because I want to restrict access to some specific folders and i've noticed I have several .htaccess files. One is in the root, the directory before public_html, is that the root, or is public_html the root? And that file enables php5 as default. I then have a htaccess doing some url re-writing in the public_html folder, then I have another one in the wordpress directory.

Is there a need for them to be spread out?

Do I have one htaccess for each folder I want affected or does the htaccess affect a folder plus all of the sub directories?

Thanks

Edit: Also have another htaccess in my wordpress theme folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache has two ways of storing configuration options:

- The central configuration (the .conf files) - when you change these, you need to restart the server.
- `.htaccess` files whose settings apply only to its directory, and all child directories. Changing these does not require a server restart

If you're on a dedicated server, you *could* theoretically migrate all `.htaccess` files into the central configuration, but WordPress will write into a `.htaccess` file when updating its permalink structure, so you'll always have at least that.

In my experience, keeping individual `.htaccess` files is relatively practical in everyday maintenance work as long as they're not *too* many. I would leave things as they are.